# Search Table row with jquery without user click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to search into a table and display only the results matching the input.

Script below is working **but** I need it to "search" only in the first column and to do it without the need of user to click the input, but get the default value="" on page load. I've tried to use val but it's not working. Also tried changing tr with td etc but it starting to malfunction.

Here's the -> **[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/G5hpZ/)** with what I've done so far.

this is the jquery.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#searchee").on('click', function() {
        var rows = $("#table").find("tr").hide();
        var data = this.value.split(" ");

        $.each(data, function(i, v) {
            rows.filter(":contains('" + v + "')").show();
        });
    });

});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
<input id="searchee" value="11 6.5 5">
```

and

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#searchee").keyup(function() {
        var rows = $("#table").find("tr").hide();
        var data = this.value.split(" ");

        $.each(data, function(i, v) {
            rows.has("td:first-child:contains('" + v + "')").show();
        });
    }).keyup();

});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/g9XcU/)

If you want to continue using placeholder then

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#searchee").keyup(function() {
        var rows = $("#table").find("tr").hide();
        var value = this.value.length == 0 ? $(this).attr('placeholder') : this.value;
        var data = value.split(" ");

        $.each(data, function(i, v) {
            rows.has("td:first-child:contains('" + v + "')").show();
        });
    }).keyup();

});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/wzY4f/)

Comment: whoa! thank you, Arun! the second script is what I needed! thank you for you help and time! :)